# How do I reshape a numpy array to remove all elements with nans?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan, reshape

I have a numpy array in python that is structured something like this:

```
array([[NaN, NaN, NaN],
       [a, b, NaN],
       [c, d, e],
       [NaN, NaN, f])
```

Each column has the same number of non-NaN values but they start and end at different rows. I would like to end up with an array structured like:

```
array([a, b, e],
      [c, d, f])
```

(That is, with all of the NaNs removed and the shape of the array modified to fit the number of data points.) However, I'm not sure how to do this efficiently.

I tried using:

```
x = x[~numpy.isnan(x)]
```

and

```
x = x[numpy.logical_not(numpy.isnan(x))]
```

but these both flattened the array.

Comment: Do you know the number of not-nan elements in advance?

Comment: In each column are they always continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Transpose the array, filter out NaNs, and reshape to it's original shape (`2` is the number of not NaN values per column).

```
x = x.T[~numpy.isnan(x.T)].reshape(-1, 2).T
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you're wanting to preserve is the number of columns:

```
num_cols = x.shape[1]
x_trimmed = x[~numpy.isnan(x)].reshape(-1, num_cols)
```

You shouldn't need to transpose the array.